# Bootstrap - Center row content below certain breakpoint

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following grid system in bootstrap v4:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto align-self-center">
            <img src="test" class="logo img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-auto align-self-center">
            <table class="table-responsive">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should have the image side-by-side with the table for screens larger than 'small' and stack them for screens smaller. This works perfectly.

Currently, everything is left-justified. I would like the row to be left justified when the columns are side-by-side (screen > "small"), but to be centred when the columns are stacked (screen < "small").

I have tried adding justify-content-center to the row, but this centres both configurations (until the screen reaches extra small, at which point it once again left-justifies...)

Not particularly helpful (because the screen is always small) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/133123/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `col-sm-auto` is that the columns become full width on `<sm` screens, and therefore the table is full width which doesn't appear centered.

Instead, use `col-auto col-sm mx-auto` on the 2nd column so that it shrinks to the width of the table on `<sm` screens...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto text-center">
            <img src="//gradientjoy.com/300x200" class="logo img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto col-sm mx-auto">
            <table class="table-responsive">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/0n3i9EGgS7

Answer (score 1):

You should use .mx-lg-auto or .mx-md-auto classes (depending on your preferable breakpoint).

Documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/).

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the left/right margin on certain screen sizes using the `ml-lg-0 mr-lg-0` classes (swap out 'lg' for the screen size you want the content to start being left justified at). That way you can use `mx-auto` to center content on small screens sizes but left justify it instead once the viewport reaches a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .row {
      background: #f8f9fa;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .col {
      border: solid 1px #6c757d;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    tbody {
      display:inline;
      width:100%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .row, table {
            text-align:center;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-auto align-self-center">
                <img src="test" class="logo img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto align-self-center">
                <table class="table-responsive">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Try this code...I have mentioned jsfiddle link also...It works for you.

Added new styles are as below,

```
tbody {
  display:inline;
  width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row, table {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/2sk5bf7t/1/